# Dynamic height width creating div clones - jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a div using jquery:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function()
{
    // jQuery('.overlay').remove(); if i use remove then its not appending the div anymore.
    var html_width = jQuery('html').width();
    var html_height = jQuery('html').height();
    jQuery('html').append('<div class="overlay"></div>').fadeIn('slow');
    jQuery('.overlay').css({'width': html_width, 'height': html_height});
});
```

Now the problem is when i resize my browser, more clones are creating. I want to remove all the previous div and append the current one.

Any help would be appreciated.

**image:**

[image: picture]

Comment: remove it then append it again on your html

Comment: @roullie its not appending when i remove it.

Comment: @ TenorB  i edited above.

Comment: Why do you need to replace it to resize?

Comment: @user3266957 It's working fine with .remove and then .append
and I don't really understand why you need it on resize!!

Comment: i know it will work perfectly fine on all devices but i want to know how to make it work on resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you keep adding it just add it once, if you want to update the height and width do it this way:

```
<script>
    jQuery('body').append('<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>');
    jQuery(window).on('load resize', function()
    {
        var html_width = jQuery('html').width();
        var html_height = jQuery('html').height();
        jQuery('body #overlay').css({ 'width': html_width, 'height': html_height });
        jQuery("#overlay").css("display", "block"); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this one?

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function()
{
    jQuery('.overlay').remove(); 
    var html_width = jQuery('html').width();
    var html_height = jQuery('html').height();
    jQuery('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    jQuery('body div.overlay').css({'width': html_width, 'height': html_height});
});
```

Comment: after i resize my browser it got deleted but never appear again.

Comment: @user3266957 which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="overlay">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).on('load resize', function(){

            var w = $(this).width();
            var h = $(this).height();

            $('.overlay').remove();

            $('body').append('<div class=overlay></div>');

        })

     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not a good practice..

Why not just do it through css properties

Comment: actually I was using this when i clicked on the pagination page numbers. using css sometimes it not covering the height because some pages have got 2 comments and some have 10 comments so there height were changing dynamically. thanks